# Wordpress REST API Endpoint

Tags: php, angularjs, wordpress, rest

I am writing an Angular WP theme and i'm trying to reduce the number of HTTP requests on the post page.

On the post page I want to list all the different taxonomies, recent posts, get the featured image and a few other things. I can do this all with individual requests with the REST API v2 plugin but that's a lot of requests.

I was hoping to create an endpoint for my theme, parse the post slug and get it all back in one request but I can't seem to figure it out.

I was thinking of using query string to get the slug. Here's what I have been using to test it out:

```
function app_get_post($data) {
    global $wp_query;

    return [
        'test' => $data,
        'vars' => $wp_query->query_vars
    ];
}

add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'app/v1', '/post', [
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'app_get_post',
    ] );
} );
```

Here's what it produces:

```
{
test: { },
vars: [ ]
}
```

I did try adding the query var with a `query_vars` hook but it didn't work either.

Any suggestions? Am I going about this the right way?

Answer (score 3):

you should pass the parameter

```
function app_get_post($data) {

    return [
        'test' => $data["postid"]        
    ];
}

add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'app/v1', '/post/(?P<postid>\d+)', [
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'app_get_post',
    ] );
} )
```

refer http://wiki.workassis.com/wordpress-create-rest-api/ for example

Answer (score 0):

So I'm learning about all this as well and haven't met success yet but will offer my research points. I know that to tap into a Custom Post Type you would need to add `show_in_rest=true` to the `register_post_type()` array or hook into it later.

However your example shows the use of post which I'm guessing should have `show_in_rest` where it is registered... I decided to check in wp-includes/post.php and it does not exist.

```
// ACCESSING A CPT FROM ANYWHERE (unable to add show_in_rest=true to the register_post_type() hook into it!)
// http://scottbolinger.com/custom-post-types-wp-api-v2/
function sb_add_cpts_to_api( $args, $post_type ) {
    if ( 'movie' === $post_type ) {
        $args['show_in_rest'] = true;
        $args['rest_base'] = 'movie';
        // $args['rest_controller_class'] = 'WP_REST_Posts_Controller';
    }
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', 'sb_add_cpts_to_api', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to pass Parameter as show below

//Endpoint : http://wpdadd.com/wp-json/api/v1/getwp/{parameter 1}/{parameter2}

```
register_rest_route( 'api', '/v1/getwp/(?P<param1>[a-z0-9\-]+)/(?P<param2>[a-z0-9\-]+)', array(
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'wpdaddStuff'

));
```

for more information you can check this example here http://wpdadd.com/create-custom-rest-api-wordpress/